# Python - Logical error in Selenium library

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, bots

I'm trying to develop a bot that automate some boring staff in a Web Application using Python/Selenium lib. The bot sometime comes to a point where it raise an "Stall Element" exception error. This happens when it tries to select from a drop down menus that are disabled and are getting enabled ONLY once the drop menu before it is selected. When I try to re-run the bot again it can select from the drop down menu without any issue.

The bot is working just fine but I don't know what's the reason of this error and why it's happening.

Here's my code as advised:

```
select_location = Select(
        self.driver.find_element(
            By.ID,
            'CPB_txtIntLocIDN'
        )
    )
    select_location.select_by_visible_text(location)
    self.wait_until('CPB_txtIntFloorIDN')

    select_floor = Select(
            self.driver.find_element(
                By.ID,
                'CPB_txtIntFloorIDN'
            )
        )

    select_floor.select_by_visible_text(floor)
    self.wait_until('CPB_txtIntSecIDN')

    select_section = Select(
        self.driver.find_element(
            By.ID,
            'CPB_txtIntSecIDN'
        )
    )
    select_section.select_by_visible_text(section)
    self.wait_until('CPB_txtIntSubIDN')

    select_subsection = Select(
        self.driver.find_element(
            By.ID,
            'CPB_txtIntSubIDN'
        )
    )
    select_subsection.select_by_visible_text(subsection)
    self.wait_until('CPB_txtIntStatusIDN')

    select_status = Select(
        self.driver.find_element(
            By.ID,
            'CPB_txtIntStatusIDN'
        )
    )
    select_status.select_by_visible_text(status)
```

and here's the wait until function code:

```
def wait_until(self, ID):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, TIMEOUT).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.ID, ID)
        )
    )
```

ExceptionError:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Thanks in advance and appreciate your help.

I tried to change the connection to the Web App to decrease the time taken to load the web objects.
I tried to increase the timeout parameter of Selenium to give the bot more time to wait until the objects get settled.

I expected that the issue should be resolved after doing the above workarounds but it still exist.

Comment: Please don't tell us stories, show us your code and errors you get.

Comment: Well, you know @undetectedSelenium  , English is not my mother tongue. I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi @Prophet, Thanks for the advise. I've included my code in the post. Please, check it out.

Comment: Note that when I try to rerun the app again it PASS successfully without any errors. that's why I thought about timeouts and connection